# What is Fastest way to load text from sqlite database in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitextview

I have an sqlite database which has a 6000 rows in it. I need to import the text from it .It successfully imports the text but takes lot of time . I dont need to import all the rows at a time , It should display the 100-300 rows in UITextView when i clicked  each cell in UITableView . the code Iam using is as follows :

@try
    {

```
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];

    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
    }
   const char *sql = "SELECT ID, MyText FROM  MyTable ";



    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
    }

    string = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    MyTextView.text=@"";
    while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {


        DetailsIDs *MyDetails = [[DetailsIDs alloc]init];

        MyDetails.MyText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];


        [MyTextView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@", MyTextView.text,MyDetails.MyText]];



    }



}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"An mmmm  exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
}
@finally
{

}
```

}

I need a fastest way to retrive the text from database,

Iam stuck ! plz help me , Thanks !

Comment: Hint:  The standard for Objective-C (and Java and C++, outside of Microsoft) is to start variable and method names with a lower-case letter, and use a leading upper-case for class names.  This makes your code significantly easier for others to follow.

Comment: Second hint:  Using repeated `stringWithFormat` calls to concatenate together 6000 strings is going to kill your performance.

Comment: Yes ! I'll keep in mind from next time ,..

Answer (score 0):

Here is your performance problem:

```
[MyTextView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@", MyTextView.text,MyDetails.MyText]];
```

You should probably use an NSMutableString and append to it, if you really want everything in one long string like that.

Comment: A simple question for u .. What is the Select query for selecting only some rows i.e., 30-50 rows out of 100.. skipping first 30 rows Thanks !